# remove elements in php array that occur more than twice

Tags: php

I am looking for a function in php,where the function must delete values in the array that shows up three times or more? For example, if you give the function array(2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 2, 0) the funciton will return array(2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 2, 0)

Comment: why is this negvoted through the floor? this is a very useful question, specifically for statistics and error correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function FilterMyArray(array &$array){

$array_count=array_count_values($array);

foreach($array_count  as $key => $value){

 if($value > 2){
     foreach (array_keys($array, $key, true) as $unsetKey) {
     unset($array[$unsetKey]);
        }
      }
   }
}
$array=array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 9);
FilterMyArray($array);
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 2 [7] => 3 [8] => 1 [9] => 9 )
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_count_values()` to get frequencies. Then use a foreach to get values that has frequency less than 3...

```
$array = array(2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 2, 0);
$frq = array_count_values($array);
$result = array();
foreach ($frq as $key=>$value){
    if ($value < 3){
        $result[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will remove all duplicates, but you'd have to add to it to count the number of each of the values.

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 2, 0);
$b = array();
for ($a as $key=>$value) {
  if (!in_array($value, $b)) {
    $b[] = $value;
  }
}
// array $b has all the values with no duplicates.
```